# What are the correct settings to enable TLS between Postfix and Dovecot via LMTP?

Tags: ssl, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am trying to get Postfix to forward mail via LMTP to Dovecot. This works fine when TLS is turned off in the settings on both sides.

Once TLS settings are enabled, Postfix connects via LMTP and Dovecot sees the connection, but both servers seem to get stuck there with no further information in the logs (logs below).

What are the correct TLS settings to make this work?

These are the relevant parts of the configuration files for both servers as currently set:

**`/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:**

```
protocols = imap lmtp

# Enable SSL (global) for IMAP connections
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/imap.domain.com/imap.domain.com.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/imap.domain.com/imap.domain.com.key


protocol lmtp {
    ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/imap.domain.com/imap.domain.com.crt
    ssl_key = </etc/ssl/imap.domain.com/imap.domain.com.key
    ssl_ca = </etc/ssl/imap.domain.com/authority.crt
    ssl_verify_client_cert = yes
    auth_ssl_require_client_cert = yes
    ssl=required
}


service lmtp {
  user = vmail
  inet_listener lmtp {
    address = * ::
    port = 24
    ssl=yes
  }
}
```

**`/etc/postfix/main.cf`**:

```
lmtp_use_tls = yes
lmtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
lmtp_tls_loglevel = 2
lmtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/lmtp_cache    
lmtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
lmtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/domain.com/authority.crt
lmtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.client.crt
lmtp_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.key    
lmtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

**Dovecot server's mail log:**

```
lmtp(1939): Info: Connect from xx.xx.xx.xx
lmtp(2500): Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
lmtp(2500): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
lmtp(2500): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
lmtp(2500): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
lmtp(2500): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
lmtp(1944): Info: Disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx: Disconnected for inactivity (state=GREETING)
```

**The Postfix Server's mail log:**

```
Nov  1 22:35:18 servername postfix/lmtp[65067]: initializing the client-side TLS engine
Nov  1 22:35:18 servername postfix/lmtp[65050]: 9935F2317D: to=<test@domain.com>, relay=remote.server.com[yy.yy.yy.yy]:24, delay=1220, delays=920/0.02/300/0, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with remote.server.com[yy.yy.yy.yy] while receiving the initial server greeting)
```

**Update**

If I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.com:24 -CAfile /etc/ssl/domain.com/authority.crt
```

on the Postfix machine, it connects via TLS to the Dovecot server via LMTP, and I can issue telnet commands to Dovecot. So it seems that Dovecot is accepting TLS connections, but when Postifx tries to connect, the negotiation stalls out.

If I run:

```
openssl s_client -starttls lmtp -connect domain.com:24 -CAfile /etc/ssl/domain.com/authority.crt
```

I just get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

and can't issue any telnet commands.

Comment: Try `openssl s_client -starttls lmtp -connect ..` to test Dovecot only, ruling out problems on the Postfix side.

Comment: In currently supported Postfix versions, you should be using `lmtp_tls_security_level` in place of the *obsolete* `lmtp_use_tls` parameter (not your problem here, just mentioning in case something else in your configuration was also not configured based on the documentation for the version you are using)

Comment: @anx I tried using `openssl s_client` (without `-starttls`) and it works. With the `-starttls` option, I just get `CONNECTED(00000003)`. I've added that as a note above. I also enabled `verbose_ssl=yes` in Dovecot, which doesn't give a lot of information, but it looks like it might be failing at `where=0x2002, ret=-1`. I added that to the log output above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (according to your openssl s_client test) properly wrapping the entire LMTP session in TLS works, and its just the STARTTLS compatibility hack that is causing trouble.. tell Postfix to do the former.

```
lmtp_tls_wrappermode=yes
```

Do verify however, that your settings to require a client cert are effective.. your `s_client` test results do not seem to have established that part yet. Also, drop the `lmtp_use_tls` settings - it is overridden and obsoleted by `lmtp_tls_security_level`.

Comment: Thank you: Postfix can now send mail to Dovecot over LMTP with TLS... as long as the verify client cert settings in Dovecot are off. When I turn on the client cert verification, Dovecot won't accept my ca certificate because it doesn't have a CRL built in. So it seems the next step is to figure out how to put some kind of dummy CRL on the CA cert to make Dovecot happy (since we don't use CRLs for this authority).

Comment: @NickLockheart `openssl ca [config..] -gencrl -crl_hold [..] -crldays [days]` lets you specify, in number of days, how long your CRL shall be considered valid. I expect that will be sufficient to let Dovecot know that it is intentional to keep using that file without it ever receiving updates. Do note that Dovecot wants you to put each CRL block directly below its respective CA, so if your CA file has two certificates.. you want one of the CRLs in the middle, the other at the end.